# GLM backtransform in proc

Tags: r, roc, back-transformation

I want to visualize and plot a ROC using `pROC` in `R`. I found this code. However, I can't track the source to find the explanation. I read the `pROC` documentation but I could not find a backtransform example. Is backtransform used right in this code?

```
# XXXX = a given species
glm.fit3 = glm(XXXX~STRATUM1+STRATUM2, data=mypts, family=binomial)
fit3.roc <- roc(mypts$XXXX, predict(glm.fit3, backtransform=TRUE))
print(plot(fit3.roc))
summary(plot(fit3.roc))
```

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: You need to ask the author of the example as predict.glm does not have such a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `backtransform` to the `predict` method for a `glm` object, so the relevant documentation is that of [`predict.glm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.glm.html). The `roc` function from `pROC` will never see this argument.

That document doesn't mention `backtransform` at all. Because it has a `...` argument as well, `backtransform` will do nothing at all and will be silently ignored.

Note that ROC curves depend only on the rank of the values, so any transformation that keep the ranking intact will make no difference at all to the ROC curve.

Comment: What else would you want to do and why? What did you expect backtransform to do in the first place?